# Formik number field accept only positive numbers

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form in which I have a number field. I am using formik for this. I need to have an input which only accepts positive numbers.

This is the codesandbox [url](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-hg4e0)

Comment: You should update question with your code

Comment: Added demo code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use regex in onChange event of Number input
Sample code:

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "", rank: -2 }}
      onSubmit={async values => {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .required("Required")
      })}
    >
      {props => {
        const {
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
          dirty,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          handleReset,
          setFieldValue
        } = props;
        return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="email" style={{ display: "block" }}>
              Email
            </label>
            <input
              id="email"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              type="text"
              value={values.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={
                errors.email && touched.email
                  ? "text-input error"
                  : "text-input"
              }
            />
            <label htmlFor="email" style={{ display: "block" }}>
              Rank
            </label>
            <input
              id="rank"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              type="number"
              value={values.rank}
              onChange={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const { value } = e.target;
                const regex = /^(0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?|0*\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$/;
                if (regex.test(value.toString())) {
                  setFieldValue("rank", value);
                }
              }}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            />
            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Code sanbox link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/formik-example-nut8p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Can you tell me the regex to allow 0 as value also?

Comment: regex to allow 0: /^(0*[0-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?|0*\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$/

Comment: Thanks. When I am trying to delete using backspace only when one digit is there, it's not allowing me.

Comment: Yes, you can check value='' in condition. Sample: if (!value || regex.test(value.toString()))

Answer (score 4):

You can add the attribute min to your input

```
<input
   id="rank"
   placeholder="Enter your rank"
   type="number"
   value={values.rank}
   min="1"
   onChange={handleChange}
   onBlur={handleBlur}
/>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add min and max to the Field element? Or do we have to go back to using input to get this basic functionality? Thanks

Comment: This is a nice idea, but as the jsfiddle below shows, it doesn't solve the issue for manual user input (in Chrome where I tested at least) https://jsfiddle.net/Almund/073ma4ng/4/

Answer (score 0):

## Pass a validate function

```
// Synchronous validation
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};

  if (!values.numberFied < 0) {
    errors.numberFied = 'Must be positive';
  }

  //...

  return errors;
};
```

Comment: This gives us validation errors. But, I don't want the negative values to be entered.

Comment: It's more user friendly to tell a user they have entered incorrect data than to hijack a users input. This about what a user expects, "I type and it works" you can tell a user afterwards that they did it wrong.